# How to add panel into another panel

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I want to add **one of** panel1,2,... into panel0 when I click on button1 .

[image]

It's my code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;


            Panel[] pnl = new Panel[3];

            while ( i<2)
            {
                pnl[i].Parent = panel0;                  // erorr

                pnl[i].BackColor = Color.PeachPuff;

                pnl[i].Size = new Size(50, 10);
                pnl[i].Location = new Point(j+5,10);
                panel0.Controls.Add(pnl[i]);
                pnl[i].BringToFront();

                i++;
                j = j + 13;
            }
         }
```

[image]

Have a suggestion ?

Comment: Could you let us know what's the error you got?

Comment: well, your panel hasn't initialized yet, you only call the array constructor, but you should still use `pnl[i] = new Panel()` before you can access its members. For the rest, you should choose between having it as parent, or assigning it to the controls of `panel0`, as both do pretty much the same

Comment: what technology is this? Winforms, WPF, webforms, Xamarin?

Comment: It's windows form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change Panel[] pnl = new Panel[3] to:

```
var pnl  = new List<Panel>{existingPanel1, existingPanel2, existingPanel3};
```

Comment: existingPanel1,2,3 are in your form.

Comment: thank you , How can I do this if the number of panels is too high?

Comment: foreach (Control control in Controls)
    if (control is Panel) // and other conditions to add to pnl list

Comment: Thanks my Friend